# How to read and show content from multiple text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, streamreader

As the question, how to show content from multiple text file? I would like to read all the content from the path show in the console with 1 press button and store into a variable. Currently it only can read 1 by one. I'm self learner and begineer for the C# currently.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListFileInDirectory(@"C:\Users\liewm\Desktop\SampleFile");

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ListFileInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
            String line;

            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
                try
                {
                    //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

                    //Read the first line of text
                    line = sr.ReadLine();

                    //Continue to read until you reach end of file
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        //write the lie to console window
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        //Read the next line
                        line= sr.ReadLine();
                    }

                    //close the file
                    sr.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use File.ReadAllText() - will be shorter. Use ParallerFor() ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to read all files in the directory simultaneously and not file after file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
   private static void ListFileInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
        String line;

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            try
            {

              //it returns string[]
             var allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);//opens a text file, reads all text and closes the text file.

             foreach(var str in allText)
             {
               //Do what you want.
             }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I add the Console.WriteLine(str); because I see you have added the comment there that line already read all the txt file.
I check the text file it can show the file at once.... but the content infront not found in console.  For example it show the content from middle of 2nd txt file to 4th txt file

Comment: Is that the console in visual studio have the limit length cannot show all the line if too long?

Comment: Seems like is console problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ListFileInDirectory(@"C:\Users\albto\Documents\_projetos\MultiplesFiles\MultiplesFiles\_arquivos");
        ListFileInDirectory(@"C:\Users\liewm\Desktop\L907C524_1x");

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
        Console.Read();
    }


    private static void ListFileInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
        List<string> allLines = new List<string>();

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            try
            {
                //stores the files address
                allLines.Add(filePath);

                //stores file lines
                allLines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }
        }

        //shows all stored lines
        allLines.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```